How to use Voximplant text chatting together with Web client?
I'm trying to find out how to create chat between two users. I can't find documentation how to configure control panel and how to write client to start chatting.

You need to do the following setup in the Voximplant Control Panel:

create a Voximplant application
create several Voximplant users in the Voximplant application

On the web client side do the initial setup

Install the Voximplant Web SDK. Ensure that you use the latest SDK version
Initialize the SDK, connect and login a Voximplant user (created in the Voximplant Control Panel)

To send a message from user1 to user2, you need:

on the user1 side get the user2's imId using VoxImplant.Messaging.Messenger.getUser API

// let's assume user2's Voximplant username is user2@app.account.voximplant.com, 
// where:
// - app is your Voximplant application name 
// - account is your Voximplant account name
let messenger = VoxImplant.Messaging.getInstance();
let userEvent = await messenger.getUser("user2@app.account");
let user2Id = userEvent.user.userId;


create a conversation between user1 and user2 via VoxImplant.Messaging.Messenger.createConversation API

let participant = {userId: user2Id};
let conversationEvent = await messenger.createConversation([participant]);
let conversation = conversationEvent.conversation;


send a message to user2 via VoxImplant.Messaging.Conversation.sendMessage API

let messageEvent = await conversation.sendMessage("text message");
// to obtain a sent message from the event
let message = messageEvent.message;

To receive messages and other messaging events, you need to subscribe on MessengerEvents. The most important for this case are:

CreateConversationEvent
SendMessageEvent

messenger.on(VoxImplant.Messaging.MessengerEvents.CreateConversation, 
  (conversationEvent) => { 
    // user2 receives this event after user1 has created a conversation
    // obtain the conversation instance from `conversationEvent` to send messages
    // from user2 to user
    let conversation = conversationEvent.conversation;
});

messenger.on(VoxImplant.Messaging.MessengerEvents.SendMessage, 
  (messageEvent) => {
    // user2 receives this event after user1 has sent a message
    // to get the text of the message
    let textMessage = messageEvent.message.text;
});


Yulia, thank you for your reply. Where is user1 here? I see only user2 create conversation and send text. as I can see in the documentation it is possible to use from 1 to N participants for the function createConversation. After that we will get the conversationEvent. Both users will be in the same conversation.

The section "To send a message from user1 to user2" describes the steps on user1 side, i.e. user1 creates a conversation and sends a message. To create conversation with more participants, you need to obtain userId of all participants and pass them to sdk api: let conversationEvent = await messenger.createConversation([participant, particpant2, participant3, ...]);

You can also add participants to the conversation after the conversation has been created via Conversation.addParticipants API - https://voximplant.com/docs/references/websdk/voximplant/messaging/conversation#addparticipants

There are also options to restrict or permit some functionality in a conversation. These options can be set on createConversation API, some of them can be changed on existing conversation. Please check the docs regarding 1. Conversation.direct - https://voximplant.com/docs/references/websdk/voximplant/messaging/conversation#direct 2. Conversation.publicJoin - https://voximplant.com/docs/references/websdk/voximplant/messaging/conversation#publicjoin 3.Conversation.uberConversation - https://voximplant.com/docs/references/websdk/voximplant/messaging/conversation#uberconversation
